# Best way to implement method on enum containing values which all implement a trait

Tags: rust, enums, traits

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with ([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4263a5583052f03ee08eed7e4dcdab9)):

```
struct FirstStruct(u64);
struct SecondStruct(u32);

trait GetValue {
    fn get_value(&self) -> u32;
}

impl GetValue for FirstStruct {
    fn get_value(&self) -> u32 {
        self.0 as u32
    }
}

impl GetValue for SecondStruct {
    fn get_value(&self) -> u32 {
        self.0
    }
}

enum MyEnum {
    First(FirstStruct),
    Second(SecondStruct),
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn get_struct_value(&self) -> u32 {
        match self {
            Self::First(data) => data.get_value(),
            Self::Second(data) => data.get_value(),
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have an enum where each variant has different data, but the structs contained in each variant all implement the same trait. The real code has many more variants, and the trait is much more complex.

This code works as is, but I'm looking for a better way to implement `get_struct_value`. I have a bunch of similar functions, and enumerating every variant in every one of them is noisy and error-prone.

Could I use macros to fill in the full match statement automatically? Or is there some other better approach?

Comment: You could add a `fn as_get_value(&self) -> &dyn GetValue` method, and then call upon that when you need it—however its implementation would still require enumerating each case, so you would have refactored your many instances of this problem into one.  If you were so inclined, you could then create a `derive` macro to automatically generate the implementation of this function from the `enum`'s definition, but that's a little involved and may be more effort than is required here?

Comment: There's probably also some 3rd-party crate that essentially provides that `derive` for you... [enum-as-inner](https://crates.io/crates/enum-as-inner) or [enum_dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) perhaps (I'm not familiar with either, just found them by searching crates.io and from a quick scan they're potentially up to the job?).

Comment: @eggyal - that's actually a nice improvement! For some reason I thought a function couldn't return two different struct types, even using `dyn`. Thanks! I'll check out those crates too, though I'm hoping to avoid unnecessary dependencies.